# Entering in Values for an Empty Binary Tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, binary-tree

I'm creating an empty complete binary tree of a certain height in an array implementation, where all the nodes currently hold None as its value.

How would I enter in a list of values so that when printing in postorder traversal, the list of values would be reversed?

Example:

```
create_empty_bt(height=3) # total nodes = 2^h - 1
values = [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
index = 0

enter_values(index, values, root)
print_tree_postorder(root, lst)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] # output
```

My code so far will print: [None, None, None, None, 5, 6, 7]

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.value = v
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


def create_empty_bt(height): # create complete binary tree
    nodes = [i for i in range(2 ** height - 1, 0, -1)]
    for i in range(height):
        start = (2 ** i) - 1
        end = (2 ** (i + 1)) - 1
        for j in range(start, end):
            nodes[j] = Node(None)
            if j == 0:
                continue
            if (j % 2) == 0:
                parent = (j - 2) // 2 # right child node
                nodes[parent].right = nodes[j]
            else:
                parent = (j - 1) // 2 # left child node
                nodes[parent].left = nodes[j]
    return nodes[0]

# Postorder = L R V, Reverse = V R L
def enter_values(index, values, root):
    if root:
        if root.value is None:
            root.value = values[index]
            enter_values(index + 1, values, root.right)
        else:
            enter_values(index + 1, values, root.left)

def print_tree(node, lst): # postorder
    if node:
        print_tree(node.left, lst)
        print_tree(node.right, lst)
        lst.append(node.value)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to prepopulate the tree with `None`? Why not just add nodes as values are added?

Comment: The way I'm creating the tree in the array will do so level by level, so if I were to print in postorder, the values wouldn't be in the correct order. So my idea was to rerun through through each node again and edit the nodes from there.

Comment: But that's not how a binary search tree works. A BST should have things less than the node on the left, and things greater than the node on the right. Then if you read left to right, it's in sorted order. Putting sorted data in a BST creates an unbalanced tree, but that's intended. You would then ideally pivot the tree the tree to rebalance it.

Comment: @blueteeth Where do you see "search"?

Comment: Use an iterator instead of indexing: `iter(sorted(values))`

Comment: `create_empty_bst`. BST stands for Binary Search Tree.

Comment: My mistake. The tree shouldn't be a BST. That's my mistake when I was typing up the code. But it is just a binary tree. I'll edit the code to match.

Comment: Hang on a minute, what kind of binary tree are you implementing where **postorder traversal** gives the values in ascending order? This would require a node to have a greater-or-equal value to all nodes in its subtree (like in a heap), but that is not a strong enough condition to give the desired behaviour. If you have a binary search tree then **inorder traversal** gives the values in ascending order.

Comment: @KevinYau it's not clear if your task is just to insert the list so post-order traversal returns the list reversed, of if you actually want the insert/traversal to sort the list you give it. In other words how would the list `[5,1,2,6,4,7,3]` show up in your traversal? Would is also be `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` or would it just be reversed?

Comment: @MarkMeyer the list would be reversed after a post-order traversal. I'll edit my post to reflect my intentions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making this a little harder than you need to. Consider that a balanced tree of height `h` is tree with two children of height `h - 1`. With this in mind you can create a tree with values of `None` simply with:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.value = v
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def create_empty_bt(height):
    if height == 0:
        return None
    n = Node(None)
    n.left = create_empty_bt(height - 1) 
    n.right = create_empty_bt(height -1)
    return n
```

To perform a post-order traversal, you just call the function on the children in the correct order:

```
def po_traverse(node):
    if node is None:
        return
    yield from po_traverse(node.left) 
    yield from po_traverse(node.right) 
    yield node.value
```

This returns a generator, to get a list just ask:

```
list(po_traverse(node))
```

To insert, you use the same technique and set the node's value to the last element of the list as the recursion unwinds:

```
def insertList(node, l):
    if node is None: 
        return 
    insertList(node.left, l)
    insertList(node.right, l)
    node.value = l.pop()
```

*Note: this consumes the list. You can avoid that by copying it or by rewriting the function such that it returns a slice of the list as it unwinds — but I though this showed the structure more clearly.*

Using this gives you:

```
> t = create_empty_bt(height=3) # total nodes = 2^h - 1
> list(po_traverse(t))
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None]

> insertList(t, [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
> list(po_traverse(t))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: I still think an iterator would be a nicer way, at least when you want to avoid consuming the list. `insertList(t, reversed(values))`. The slicing idea sounds complicated.

Comment: @KevinYau I'm not sure what you're asking. The root of the above tree is `7` -- the last element produced by post-order traversal. Its left child will be `3` and right child will be `6`. It might help to make a sketch of the tree and compare where elements are in the original list.

Comment: I'll work it out. Thanks for the comments and help.